# How to GZIP Compress an http request in Go?

Tags: go, gzip

My application is rejecting this, but when I curl the data it is working, so it seems there is somewhere that I am confused with how to compress this http payload in Go.

```
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    g := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
    g.Write([]byte("apples")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", q.host, bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
    ...
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

Does someone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the main issue is that I needed to close the gzip Writer:

```
b, err := batch.Json()
....
var buf bytes.Buffer
g := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
if _, err = g.Write(b); err != nil {
    slog.Error(err)
    return
}
if err = g.Close(); err != nil {
    slog.Error(err)
    return
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", q.host, &buf)
```

Comment: you don't need to wrap buf in a `bytes.Reader` -- it already fulfills a Reader interface.

Comment: @JimB: Various variations seem to return an error, can you show me the actual code change you recommend?

Comment: (my guess) Buffer.Read has a pointer receiver so you need the address of buf e.g. `http.NewRequest("POST", q.host, &buf)`

Comment: Wrong guess. You have to wrap the buff with a reader. It didn't work for me without the reader.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to use the copy function

```
func HttpHandler2(req *http.Request) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    g := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)

    _, err := io.Copy(g, &b)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error(err)
        return
    }    
}
```